# How can I prevent Vuex from interfering with my class instance?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex, prose-mirror

I am trying to store an instance of a class in Vuex (the [`EditorState`](https://prosemirror.net/docs/ref/#state.EditorState) from ProseMirror). This class is more or less immutable from the outside, meaning that whenever I want to make changes to it, I will just put a new instance of the class into Vuex.

As such, I do not need Vue's change tracking here, and in fact it actually seems to interfere with the internal workings of ProseMirror, so I was wondering if there was a way that I could isolate my object from Vue so that it is treated atomically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by taking the suggestion from the top answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44307531/3508956) and freezing my class instance before giving it to Vuex.

```js
const store = new Store<AppState>({
    state: {
        editor: Object.freeze(editorState), // freeze because Vue reactivity messes it up
        filename: null,
        metadata: {}
    },
    mutations: {
        updateDocument(context, transaction: Transaction) {
            console.log("updateDocument called");

            // freeze again
            context.editor = Object.freeze(context.editor.apply(transaction));
        }
    },
    strict: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
});
```

Since [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) is not recursive, this doesn't have any effect on the internal workings of ProseMirror, but it discourages Vue from trying to modify the object.

Comment: Do you implement a getter? (If not, why put it into vuex?) I tried this approach but the vue browser plugin was then crashing on it (due to it being large, not due to it being frozen, as far as I can tell).