# how to stop a variable to sync Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I return a variable as a result of

```
  async asyncData({ redirect, params, store }) {
```

and that variable is:

```
  return {
    camera: c,
```

I am trying to clone it as

```
  created() {
    this.dummyCamera = this.camera
```

but even when I change anything to `dummyCamera`, it gets changed in `this.camera` too?

How I can stop this behaviour?

I want to compare both `dummyCamera` as well as `this.camera` when I change anything in dummyCamera, but right now I am unable to do so.

Even If I change anything in this.camera,

```
camera: {
  handler: function(newValue) {
    console.log(newValue)
    console.log(this.camera)
  },
  deep: true
}
```

both `newValue` and `this.camera` are the same? How I can stop this sync?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restrict vue/vuex reactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44307077/restrict-vue-vuex-reactivity)

Comment: even on doing Object.freez, nothing gets freez, change in one object changing in other too

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility to stop the sync is

```
  created() {
    this.dummyCamera = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.camera))
```

this way you can use your newly assigned variable.