# In VueJS, where to store FabricJS instances? Window? Vuex? Component data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, canvas, vuex, fabricjs

Where I'm suposed to store FabricJS instances in VueJS?
I tried to store it in Vuex state but Fabric instances has lots of internal methods that update the instance and triggers a "Don't mutate state outside Vuex mutations" error.

Comment: To be able to help you better, it would be necessary to have some pieces of your code

Comment: Which version of Vue? And when you say FabricJS instance, do you mean the fabric module, or a canvas you're creating with Fabric?

Comment: @MattP
- I'm using Nuxt2 / Vue2
- Fabric instance, not the module.

Answer (score 1):

I see you're using Vue2, and to help Vue3 users I'll touch on it as well.

I would want to store a Fabric.js canvas in a way that won't have reactivity injected into it. Otherwise [performance](https://codeburst.io/5-vue-performance-tips-98e184338439) will likely be awful.

To store it in Vuex or component data, you can use `Object.freeze()` and in Vue3 there is `shallowRef`. Both are [described a bit here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44307077/restrict-vue-vuex-reactivity).

Another option is to look into some of the [state functions](https://vueuse.org/functions.html#category=State) in VueUse, which supports Nuxt2/Vue2 and Nuxt3/Vue3.

Although not as friendly outside of .vue files, `provide` and `inject` in [Vue2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject) or [Vue3](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#provide-inject) components can be useful to share objects.

Storing in `window` is easy and convenient, but globals tend to come back to haunt me later. I'd use something from the options above to keep the canvas scoped.

Comment: I've used to store instances globally in window but it looks kinda wrong to me.
Object.freeze(), seems pretty interesting, maybe it solves the "Do not mutate state outside mutatios" and the performance issues, wich I had to bypass by setting strict mode off on dev.
I'll try it out.